# regex for { } within ' 's

Tags: c#, .net, regex, c#-4.0, desktop-application

An example,

I have a string that contains let's say:

> function main {
>
> // TODO  print 'hello {cmd get world}
>   world {nice}!'s asdads
>
> }

How can I select only the words that are in within {}'s and that are inside a ''string. This example would retrieve the output:

> {cmd get world; nice}

thanks a lot!

Comment: With or without escaping (of `'`, `{`, and `}`) allowed? What if the '...' was embedded in a string (i.e. `"...'{foo}'..."`)?

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool for this, a parser generator will serve much better.

Comment: not including the { } so the answer should just be:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?<='[^']+\{)[^\{\}]+(?=\}[^']+')`

Should do the trick.

**Edit**: Updated regex to use lookbehind and -aheads.

**Edit 2**: Regex now matches only the text inside the braces and nothing else.

Comment: Nope. \'[^'].*?{([^}]*)}.*?'\, that will get the first {}, but not the second {}. You could also just use \'([^']*)'\ to get the first part, and then \{([^}]*)}\ to get all matches within that.

Comment: doesn't seem to be working http://www.regexpal.com/?flags=&regex=%5C'%5B^'%5D*%5C{(%5B^%5C}%5D%2B)%5C}%5B^'%5D*%5C'&input=function%20main%20{%0A%0A%20%2F%2F%20TODO%0A%20print%20'hello%20{cmd%20get%20world}%20world%20{nice}!'s%20asdads%0A%0A}

Comment: I've already updated the answer 5 minutes ago, and tested it. This one should be working. @luis, @Twisted Pear

Comment: for the case function main {

 // TODO
 print 'hello {cmd as s}wo{lol}rld!'

}

it is selecting all the way until rld!' for the second selection

Comment: @luis, are you sure? I just tested it on [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester/) and it works just fine (selects `cmd as s` and `lol`).